# I need to create a decimal to binary program that can receive input of up to 100,000,000 and output the whole answer without displaying rubbish

Tags: c, loops, binary, printf, decimal

As you've read, I created a decimal to binary program and it works well, but it cannot handle user input equal to 100,000,000. My solution is to print each character as it goes, but I do not know what the appropriate loop to use is, and I am also not that great with the math so the main formula to be used is unclear to me. Arrays are not allowed. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int input,inp,rem=0,ans=0,place_value=1,ans;
int main()
{
    printf("\nYou have chosen Decimal to Binary and Octal Conversion!\n");
    printf("Enter a decimal number:\n");  
    scanf("%llu", &input);
    inp=input;
    while(input){
        rem=input%2;
        input=input/2;
        ans=ans+(rem*place_value);
        place_value=place_value*10;
    }
    printf("%llu in Decimal is %llu in Binary Form.\n", inp,ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I have already read all your answers and I have done my best to understand them. I was able to understand most of what was brought up but some terms or lessons mentioned will require more time from me to learn. I have already submitted my output without solving the 100,000,000 issue but I intend to use the knowledge I have now to create better outputs. I tried asking a friend of mine and he told me he was able to do it using method 2 found here:https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary. Perhaps my instructor simply wanted to teach us how to fully utilize control structures and data types which is why there are so many restrictions. Thank you all for your time and god bless.

Comment: Where are your includes? [Edit] and add them. They are part of your code and should be posted. Read this: [mcve]. BTW your code does not compile. Post real code and not some made up stuff.

Comment: you're most likely overflowing `unsigned long long`. No arrays means no strings?

Comment: The binary representation of a given number has more than three times as many digits as the decimal representation (because 10 > 2^3).  That will limit your approach of encoding binary digits as decimal digits, which is a bit fraught in the first place.

Comment: I would suggest taking a different approach: extract the binary digits and print them one by one instead of encoding them into one `unsigned long long` and printing them with one `printf()` call.  That will be complicated by the fact that you want to print them most-significant bit first, whereas it is arithmetically easiest to pull them out least-significant first.  That can be overcome without using arrays in a variety of ways.  Some are messy and / or tedious, but there is a recursive solution that is fairly tidy.

Comment: Definitely an overflow of `unsigned long long`. Your code is correct, but you're abusing decimal numbers for displaying binary and at some point your decimal numbers are becoming too large to fit into an `unsigned long long`. You should use [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) for this.

Comment: Note: `100,000,000` is a 27-bit number.  `"%llu"` is an array, so "Arrays are not allowed" deserves qualification.

Comment: Why are arrays not allowed?  Are you stranded on a desert island, and the `[` and `]` keys on your keyboard got lost in the shipwreck?  Seriously, why is your instructor giving you this pointless restriction?  A decently-written base converter wants to be encapsulated as a function, and a string (i.e. an array) is the *only* sensible output datatype.  Or, if you're not interested in an encapsulatable function, you can just print the digits (or, in this case, the binary bits) out as you generate them, without trying to store them anywhere.

Comment: @Lapnesnoj You may not get any credit from him, but ***I*** will give you 100 extra credit points if you walk up to your instructor and tell him he's a nudnik.  Sheesh.

Comment: Converting a "decimal" number, represented as an integer of any size, to a "binary" number, represented as another integer, is a terrible, terrible way to do it.  But if you're not allowed to use arrays, it's probably the only way to do it, since the only other ways are to (a) put characters into an array and reverse the array if necessary, and (b) use recursion, as in chux's answer, which is elegant in its way but not something an instructor should be asking a beginning programmer to come up with.  All in all this is a terrible, terrible assignment.

Comment: @Lapnesnoj If you have a minute, I'd be curious to hear what sort of solution your instructor expected for this exercise, if you know.

Comment: @SteveSummit I intend to ask him the solution he expected but the activity isn't over, we are to modify this program so it utilizes functions. After I resubmit, I will try to ask him about his intended solution.

Answer (score 3):

So as the comments have explained, the decimal number 100000000 has the 27-bit binary representation `101111101011110000100000000`.  We can therefore store that in a 32-bit int with no problem.  But if we were to try to store the *decimal* number 101111101011110000100000000, which just happens to *look* like a binary number, well, that would require 87 bits, so it won't even fit into a 64-bit `long long` integer.

And the code in this question does try to compute its result, `ans`, as a decimal number which just happens to look like a binary number.  And for that reason this code can't work for numbers larger than 1048575 (assuming a 64-bit `unsigned long long int`).

And this is one reason that "decimal to binary" conversion (or, for that matter, conversion to *any* base) should normally *not* be done to a result variable that's an integer.  Normally, the result of such a conversion — to any base — should either be done to a result variable that's a *string*, or it should be printed out immediately.  (The moral here is that the base only matters when a number is printed out for a human to read, which implies either a string, and/or something printed to, say, `stdout`.)

However, in C a string is of course an array.  So asking someone to do base conversion *without* using arrays is a perverse, pointless exercise.

If you print the digits out immediately, you don't have to store them in an array.  But the standard algorithm — repeated division by 2 (or whatever the base is) generates digits in reverse order, from least-significant to most-significant, which ends up being right-to-left, which is the wrong order to just print them out.  Conventional convert-to-digits code usually stores the computed digits into an array, and then reverses the array — but if there's a prohibition against using arrays, this strategy is (again pointlessly) denied to us.

The other way to get the digits out in the other order is to use a recursive algorithm, as @chux has demonstrated in his answer.

But just to be perverse in my own way, I'm going to show another way to do it.

Even though it's generally a horrible idea, constructing the digits into an integer, that's in base 10 but *looks* like it's in base 2, is at least one way to store things up and get the answer back out with the digits in the right order.  The only problem is that, as we've seen, the number can get outrageously big, especially for base 2.  (The other problem, not that it matters here, is that this approach won't work for bases greater than 10, since there's obviously no way to construct a decimal number that just happens to look like it's in, say, base 16.)

The question is, how can we represent integers that might be as big as 87 bits?  And my answer is, we can use what's called "multiple precision arithmetic".  For example, if we use a *pair* of 64-bit `unsigned long long int` variables, we can theoretically represent numbers up to 128 bits in size, or 340282366920938463463374607431768211455!

Multiple precision arithmetic is an advanced but fascinating and instructive topic.  Normally it uses arrays, too, but if we limit ourselves to just two "halves" of our big numbers, and make certain other simplifications, we can do it pretty simply, and achieve something just powerful enough to solve the problem in the question.

So, to repeat, we're going to represent a 128-bit number as a "high half" and a "low half".  Actually, to keeps things simpler, it's not actually going to be a 128-bit number.  To keep things simpler, the "high half" is going to be the first 18 digits of a 36-digit decimal number, and the "low half" is going to be the other 18 digits.  This will give us the equivalent of of only about 120 bits, but it will still be plenty for our purposes.

So how do we do arithmetic on 36-digit numbers represented as "high" and "low" halves?  Actually, it ends up being more or less the same way we learned how to do pencil-and-paper arithmetic on numbers represented as digits, at all.

If I have one of these "big" numbers, in its two halves:

```
  high1  low1
```

and if I have a second one, also in two halves:

```
  high2  low2
```

and if I want to compute the sum

```
  high1  low1
+ high2  low2
  -----------
  high3  low3
```

the way I do it is to add `low1` and `low2` to get the low half of the sum, `low3`.  If `low3` is less than 1000000000000000000 — that is, if it has 18 digits or less — I'm okay, but if it's bigger than that, I have a carry into the next column.  And then to get the high half of the sum, `high3`, I just add `high1` plus `high2` plus the carry, if any.

Multiplication is harder, but it turns out for this problem we're never going to have to compute a full 36-digit × 36-digit product.  We're only ever going to have to multiply one of our big numbers by a small number, like 2 or 10.  The problem will look like this:

```
  high1  low1
×         fac
  -----------
  high3  low3
```

So, again by the rules of paper-and-pencil arithmetic we learned long ago, `low3` is going to be `low1` × `fac`, and `high3` is going to be `high1` × `fac`, again with a possible carry.

The next question is how we're going to carry these low and high halves around.  As I said, normally we'd use an array, but we can't here.  The second choice might be a struct, but you may not have learned about those yet, and if your crazy instructor won't let you use arrays, it seems that using structures might well be out of bounds, also.  So we'll just write a few functions that accept high and low halves as separate arguments.

Here's our first function, to add two 36-digit numbers.  It's actually pretty simple:

```
void long_add(unsigned long long int *hi, unsigned long long int *lo,
                unsigned long long int addhi, unsigned long long int addlo)
{
    *hi += addhi;
    *lo += addlo;
}
```

The way I've written it, it doesn't compute `c = a + b`; it's more like `a += b`.  That is, it takes `addhi` and `addlo` and adds them in to `hi` and `lo`, modifying `hi` and `lo` in the process.  So `hi` and `lo` are passed in as pointers, so that the pointed-to values can be modified.  The high half is `*hi`, and we add in the high half of the number to be added in, `addhi`.  And then we do the same thing with the low half.  And then — whoops — what about the carry?  That's not too hard, but to keep things nice and simple, I'm going to defer it to a separate function.  So my final `long_add` function looks like:

```
void long_add(unsigned long long int *hi, unsigned long long int *lo,
                unsigned long long int addhi, unsigned long long int addlo)
{
    *hi += addhi;
    *lo += addlo;
    check_carry(hi, lo);
}
```

And then `check_carry` is simple, too.  It looks like this:

```
void check_carry(unsigned long long int *hi, unsigned long long int *lo)
{
    if(*lo >= 1000000000000000000ULL) {
        int carry = *lo / 1000000000000000000ULL;
        *lo %= 1000000000000000000ULL;
        *hi += carry;
    }
}
```

Again, it accepts pointers to `lo` and `hi`, so that it can modify them.

The low half is `*lo`, which is supposed to be at most an 18-bit number, but if it's got 19 — that is, if it's greater than or equal to 1000000000000000000, that means it has overflowed, and we have to do the carry thing.  The carry is the extent by which `*lo` exceeds 18 digits — it's actually just the top 19th (and any greater) digit(s).  If you're not super-comfortable with this kind of math, it may not be immediately obvious that taking `*lo`, and dividing it by that big number (it's literally 1 with eighteen 0's) will give you the top 19th digit, or that using `%` will give you the low 18 digits, but that's *exactly* what `/` and `%` do, and this is a good way to learn that.

In any case, having computed the carry, we add it in to `*hi`, and we're done.

So now we're done with addition, and we can tackle multiplication.  For our purposes, it's just about as easy:

```
void long_multiply(unsigned long long int *hi, unsigned long long int *lo,
                                            unsigned int fac)
{
    *hi *= fac;
    *lo *= fac;
    check_carry(hi, lo);
}
```

It looks eerily similar to the addition case, but it's just what our pencil-and-paper analysis said we were going to have to do.  (Again, this is a simplified version.)  We can re-use the same `check_carry` function, and that's why I chose to break it out as a separate function.

With these functions in hand, we can now rewrite the binary-to-decimal program so that it will work with these even bigger numbers:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int inp, input;
    unsigned long long int anslo = 0, anshi = 0;
    unsigned long long int place_value_lo = 1, place_value_hi = 0;
    
    printf("Enter a decimal number:\n");
    scanf("%u", &input);
    inp = input;

    while(input){
        int rem = input % 2;
        input = input / 2;

        // ans=ans+(rem*place_value);
        unsigned long long int tmplo = place_value_lo;
        unsigned long long int tmphi = place_value_hi;
        long_multiply(&tmphi, &tmplo, rem);
        long_add(&anshi, &anslo, tmphi, tmplo);

        // place_value=place_value*10;
        long_multiply(&place_value_hi, &place_value_lo, 10);
    }

    printf("%u in Decimal is ", inp);
    if(anshi == 0)
         printf("%llu", anslo);
    else printf("%llu%018llu", anshi, anslo);
    printf(" in Binary Form.\n");
}
```

This is basically the same program as in the question, with these changes:

- The `ans` and `place_value` variables have to be greater than 64 bits, so they now exist as `_hi` and `_lo` halves.
- We're calling our new functions to do addition and multiplication on big numbers.
- We need a `tmp` variable (actually `tmp_hi` and `tmp_lo`) to hold the intermediate result in what used to be the simple expression `ans = ans + (rem * place_value);`.
- There's no need for the user's `input` variable to be big, so I've reduced it to a plain `unsigned int`.

There's also some mild trickiness involved in printing the two halves of the final answer, `anshi` and `anslo`, back out.  But if you compile and run this program, I think you'll find it now works for any input numbers you can give it.  (It should theoretically work for inputs up to 68719476735 or so, which is bigger than will fit in a 32-bit input `inp`.)

---

Also, for those still with me, I have to add a few disclaimers.  The only reason I could get away with writing `long_add` and `long_multiply` functions that looked so small and simple was that they *are* simple, and work only for "easy" problems, without undue overflow.  I chose 18 digits as the maximum for the "high" and "lo" halves because a 64-bit `unsigned long long int` can actually hold numbers up to the equivalent of 19 digits, and that means that I can detect overflow — of up to one digit — simply, with that `> 1000000000000000000ULL` test.  If any intermediate result ever overflowed by *two* digits, I'd have been in real trouble.  But for simple additions, there's only ever a single-digit carry.  And since I'm only ever doing tiny multiplications, I could cheat and assume (that is, get away with) a single-digit carry there, too.

If you're trying to do multiprecision arithmetic in full generality, for multiplication you have to consider partial products that have up to twice as many digits/bits as their inputs.  So you either need to use an output type that's twice as wide as the inputs, or you have to split the inputs into halves ("sub-halves"), and work with them individually, basically doing a little 2×2 problem, with various carries, for each "digit".

Another problem with multiplication is that the "obvious" algorithm, the one based on the pencil-and-paper technique everybody learned in elementary school, can be unacceptably inefficient for really big problems, since it's basically O(N<sup>2</sup>) in the number of digits.
People who do this stuff for a living have lots of more-sophisticated techniques they've worked out, for things like detecting overflow and for doing multiplication more efficiently.
And then if you want some real fun (or a real nightmare, full of bad flashbacks to elementary school), there's long division...

Answer (score 1):

OP's code suffers from overflow in `place_value*10`

---

A way to avoid *no array* and range limitations is to use recursion.

Perhaps beyond where OP is now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lsbit(unsigned long long x) {
  if (x > 1) {
    print_lsbit(x / 2); // Print more significant digits first
  }
  putchar(x % 2 + '0'); // Print the LSBit
}

int main(void) {
  printf("\nYou have chosen Decimal to Binary and Octal Conversion!\n");
  printf("Enter a decimal number:\n");
  //scanf("%llu", &input);
  unsigned long long input = 100000000;
  printf("%llu in Decimal is ", input);
  print_lsbit(input);
  printf(" in Binary Form.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
You have chosen Decimal to Binary and Octal Conversion!
Enter a decimal number:
100000000 in Decimal is 101111101011110000100000000 in Binary Form.
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but I agree, certainly not something a beginning student should be asked to come up with.