# c program to generate binary number starting from 1 till n

Tags: c, visual-studio, binary, logic, decimal

i need  a output like if number is 5 the output should be the 5 binary numbers till 5 but starting from 1 have given example below. it is to be done without using arrays

**input:5
output:1,10,11,100,101**

but i am getting
output like
this
**input=5
output=1,11,11,111,111**

is this error beacause of wrong instruction
any hint or solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void binary_number(int n)
{

    int bin_n = 0;

    int i = 0;

    while (n > 0)
    {

        bin_n = n % 2;

        n = n / 2;

        i++;

    }
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)

        printf("%d", bin_n, j);

    printf("\n");
}
void binary_number_generation(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)

    {
        binary_number(i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter the end value:");

    scanf("%d", &n);


    printf("\nBinary Number from 1 to %d:", n);

    printf("\n");

    binary_number_generation(n);

}
```

here i am with a new code idk what i have done but it does give the results

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i=0,bin=0,plc,dig=0,j;
    printf("Enter the n value : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nBinary numbers from 1 to %d : ",n);
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        plc=0;bin=0;dig=0;
        for(plc=1,j=i;j>0;j=j/2)
        {
            dig=j%2;
            bin=bin+(dig*plc);
            plc=plc*10;
        }
        printf("%d\n",bin);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not your fault, but: this is a nearly impossible problem.  We've seen several variations on it (perhaps your classmates, under the same sadistic instructor?) over the past couple of weeks.

Comment: The "nearly impossible" part referenced by @SteveSummit is getting the bits in the right order (e.g. 100 rather than 001 for 4). Recursion with a post-traversal print would do the trick.

Comment: You are probably not going to be able to solve it all at once.  I suggest first solving one of these two easier problems: (1) Print the first N binary numbers, but you *are* allowed to use arrays. (2) Print the first N binary numbers, where each number has its digits *backwards*.  That is, 4 is `001`,   5 is `101`, 6 is `011`, 8 is `0001`, 10 is `0101`, etc.  Once you've got one of those working, then you can tackle your actual problem.  And I was about to give you the same hint ikegami did: recursion.

Comment: The reason the code you posted doesn't work is basically that `bin_n` is not an array.  If it were an appropriately-indexed array, your code would work fine.

Comment: @SteveSummit ik its not possible without arrays atleast for a beginner like me hope someone does come with a solution :(

Comment: Related: [I need to create a decimal to binary program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586409/i-need-to-create-a-decimal-to-binary-program-that-can-receive-input-of-up-to-100).

Comment: @SteveSummit yes bin_n isnt array if it was it could fix my problem but the main problem is no using arrays :(((((( Thanks tho:)

Comment: If only C's `printf` could do binary conversion

Comment: (It's also possible without recursion by converting each bit to a digit.)

Comment: The first loop in your `binary_number` function is correct.  It successfully generates binary bits `bin_n`, `1` or `0`.  The problem is that it generates them in right-to-left order.  You have three options: (1) Stuff them into an array.  (This is the right way to do it, but it has been perversely denied to you.) (2) Use recursion: Have `binary_number` call itself to print `n/2`, then print the last bit. (3) Multiply the digits by successive powers of 10 and stuff the digits into an integer variable, resulting in a decimal number that *looks* like a binary number.

Comment: Number (3) is a stupid, stupid way to do it, that nobody should be teaching or encouraging students to use.  Also it severely (and quite artificially/unnecessarily) limits the size of the numbers you can successfully convert (no more than 1023, for 32-bit ints), but it's one way around your perverse restriction.

Comment: *idk what i have done but it does give the results* You have successfully implemented what my comment above calls "number 3", and what ikegami has dubbed "Decimal-coded binary".  It's what both ikegami's and MED LDN's answers are suggesting.  It's normally a horrible way of converting to binary, but given the silly no-arrays rule, it's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take 6 for example.

6<sub>10</sub> = **1** * 2<sup>2</sup> + **1** * 2<sup>1</sup> + **0** * 2<sup>0</sup> = **110**<sub>2</sub>

Normally, when building an binary number, you'd use an array. But we can't. But what if we could convert 110 base 2 (six) to the number 110 base 10 (one hundred and ten).

**110**<sub>10</sub> = **1** * 10<sup>2</sup> + **1** * 10<sup>1</sup>  + **0** * 10<sup>0</sup>

That looks doable!

```
6 base 10 = 1 * 2^2  + 1 * 2^1  + 0 * 2^0  = 110 base 2

            |          |          |
            v          v          v

            1 * 10^2 + 1 * 10^1 + 0 * 10^0 = 110 base 10
```

We'll refer to this format as decimal-coded binary (a reference to [binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)). What this would allow us to do is use `printf %d` or the likes to print the number.

Solution follows. You should try to implement it yourself before reading on.

---

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Converts XYZ (base 2) to XYZ (base 10)
// 8 bit inputs require ceil(log2(11111111)) = 24 bit outputs.
// 16 bit inputs require ceil(log2(1111111111111111)) = 50 bit outputs.
uint64_t to_dcb(uint16_t n) {
   uint64_t dcb = 0
   uint64_t factor = 1;
   while (n > 0) {
      dcb += (n & 1) * factor;
      n >>= 1;
      factor *= 10;
   }

   return dcb;
}

int main(void) {
   printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", to_dcb(6));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your term "decimal-coded binary".  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586409/i-need-to-create-a-decimal-to-binary-program-that-can-receive-input-of-up-to-100/69590952#69590952) for how to do it for inputs up to 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code is about to converting each number from 1 to n to binary form

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* This function is to convert the number of digits and then calculate the rest of division 
  if it's 1 or 0 and then we will form the new number in binary form */

int binary_number(n)
{
    int m=0,q=1,s=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        s+=(n%2)*q;
        q*=10;
        n/=2;
    }
    return s;
}

/* This number is using to display each number from 1 to n in binary form, 
   it's better to use an array in next time */         

void binary_number_generation(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n",binary_number(i));
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the end value:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    binary_number_generation(n);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method of generating the binary representation of an integer.  It's got several problems, *but*, it has the advantage that it generates the digits in left-to-right order, so you can print them out right away, without having to store them in an array.

```
void binary_number(int n)
{
    int big = 32768;
    while(big > 0) {
        if(n >= big) {
            putchar('1');
            n -= big;
        } else {
            putchar('0');
        }

        big /= 2;
    }
}
```

Exercise for the student: modify it so it doesn't print leading 0's.

Exercise #2: What happens if you try this function on a number bigger than 65535?  Can you fix it?