# c integer to binary number

Tags: c, binary, transformation

I would be really glad if any one could help me out...

I should write a program, that prints an integer in binary representation without using loops. It also needs to print out the number in 32 bits representation. For small numbers (e.g. 256 still works) the code below works fine. For big numbers i don't get the expected output.

Does anybody see how I can fix this?

Thanks a lot!

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
print_reverse(uint32_t value)
{

    if (value % 10 == 0) {
        if (value == 0) {
            printf("1");
            return;
        } else {
            printf("0");
            print_reverse(value / 10);
        }
    } else {
        if (value == 1) {
            return;
        } else {
            printf("1");
            print_reverse((value - 1) / 10);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int
print_binary1(uint32_t value, uint32_t binary1, int zeros1)
{
    int rest, binary, zeros;
    if (value == 0) {
        zeros = zeros1;
        printf("%0*d", 32 - zeros, 0);
        return binary1;
    } else {
        rest = value % 2;
        if (rest >= 1) {
            binary = binary1 * 10 + 1;
            zeros = zeros1 + 1;
            return print_binary1((value - 1) / 2, binary, zeros);
        } else {
            binary = binary1 * 10;
            zeros = zeros1 + 1;
            return print_binary1(value / 2, binary, zeros);
        }
    }
}

void
print_binary(uint32_t value)
{
    printf("%" PRIu32, value);
    if (value == 0) {
        printf(" = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001");
    } else {
        printf(" = 0b");
        int binary = print_binary1(value, 1, 0);
        print_reverse(binary);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    uint32_t value;
    printf("value: ");
    if (scanf("%" SCNu32, &value) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: While reading the 'uint32_t' value an error occurred!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("\n");
    print_binary(value);
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Indentation, and consistent indentation, is very important for people trying to understand your code.

Comment: I think that the `scanf` format is for `#define SCNu32 'lu'` but you are providing a pointer to `uint32_t value;` not `unsigned long`.

Comment: *For small numbers the code works*. Is this because you are entering a 'fake' binary number as decimal, for example `1001` as the supposed binary? The largest `unsigned` number comprising `0`s and `1`s is `1111111111` which as if binary would be `1023` decimal.

Comment: @WeatherVane: According to [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_constants_for_the_fscanf_family_of_functions), `SCNu32` does expand to the correct `fscanf` conversion format specifier for `uint32_t`. Therefore, in this respect, I see nothing wrong in OP's code.

Comment: I don't think i'm entering fake binary numbers. I have tried 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 16, 32 or 256 and they are all fine. 512 isn't.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks my source must have been for an implementation where `unsigned long` is 32 bits (and I see now that it has `#define SCNu16 'u'`).

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's impossible to do using loops unless you have 32 versions of virtually the same line of code.

For example, the code in question uses recursion to achieve looping. (In fact, any loop can be achieved using recursion.) But it's still looping (executing the same code repeatedly).

The simplest way to achieve what you want while hiding the looping would be to use `snprintf`.

---

The rest answers why the code doesn't work for larger numbers.

It looks like this produces what I [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775090/589924) called "decimal-coded binary" (in reference to [binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)), where each digit of the decimal representation represents a bit. For example, it converts thirteen (1101 base 2) to one thousand one hundred and one (1101 base 10).

If so, the largest input the program supports is 1,1111,1111 (base 2) because 10,0000,0000 (base 10) doesn't fit in a `uint32_t`. Put differently, a 32 bit output supports a floor(log10(2^32-1)) = 9 bit input. This means the program support number from 0 to 511, but not beyond.

By switching to a 64 bit output, you could support a floor(log10(2^64-1)) = 19 bit input, which is still not enough for want you want to do.

You need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The "without looping" is a silly constraint. If it is a programming exercises, it can make sense, if the suggestion is to use some replacement for a loop, like recursion or loop unrolling, but those are really just loops wearing a fake beard and speaking in an obviously made up accent. You need to output 32 characters, and you can easily do that by just looking at 32 bits and be done with it.

Anyway, here's a way to do it without any loops, because I simply unrolled the loop. (I'm not going to write 32 statements, so I cheat a little and use a table).

```c
// a table for 4-bit numbers to get us started...
char *bits[] = {
    "0000",
    "0001",
    "0010",
    "0011",
    "0100",
    "0101",
    "0110",
    "0111",
    "1000",
    "1001",
    "1010",
    "1011",
    "1100",
    "1101",
    "1110",
    "1111",
};

// brute force, which is essentially loop unrolling
void print_bits_brute(uint32_t i)
{
#define B(offset) bits[(i >> offset) & 0xf]
    printf("0b%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n",
           B(28), B(24), B(20), B(16), B(12), B(8), B(4), B(0));
#undef B
}
```

The unrolling happens in `print_bits_brute()`, and as you can see, this would have been a lot easier with just a loop. Such a loop could look like:

```c
void print_bits_loop(uint32_t i)
{
    printf("0b");
    for (int b = 28; b >= 0; b -= 4)
    {
        printf("%s", bits[(i >> b) & 0xf]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It does the same thing. If there is some speed to be gained by unrolling the loop, the compiler knows how to translate the constants in the loop to something appropriate, so there probably isn't anything to gain by unrolling yourself.

If you have to do it recursively, that is easy enough. It is a loop by another name. Well, not quite, since this code isn't tail-recursive, but it is close enough.

```c
// b must be a power of two here...
void print_bits_b(uint32_t i, int b)
{
    if (b == 4)
    {
        printf("%s", bits[i & 0xf]);
    }
    else
    {
        b >>= 1;
        print_bits_b(i >> b, b);
        print_bits_b(i, b);
    }
}

void print_bits_recursive(uint32_t i)
{
    printf("0b");
    print_bits_b(i, 32);
    printf("\n");
}
```

A 32-bit integer can be split into two 16-bit integers. Those 16-bit integers can be split into four 8-bit integers, and they can in turn be split into eight 4-bit integers. Those we can handle directly with the table.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is: C has no Data-type for the numbers based on 2.
So follow the mathematic rules of numbers based on 2 and build a simple recursion:

```
void num2byte(unsigned char number){
    unsigned char num=255;
     short index=7;
     num=number;
     while(num!=0){
        bitmuster[index]=num%2;
        num=num/2;
        printf("%d",bitmuster[index]);
        index--;
     }
     printf("\n");
 }
```

bitmuster is a :

```
 typedef unsigned char bits[8];
```

Design by your self: the range here is 8 and input type unsigned char.

the results for big endian is:

210

01001011

if you want little endian turn around:

```
    for(int z=7;z>-1;z--){
        printf("%d",bitmuster[z]);
    }
```

the result is:

11010010

I think without loop - no way

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *'C has no Data-type for the numbers based on 2.'* Can you elaborate?

Comment: The smallest type in C is a char. If you want to operate or represent numbers based on 2 (only 1 and 0), you have to code it.

Comment: What about `_Bool` or bitfields in `struct`?

Comment: Look at the memory allocation. C takes at least 1 byte as I think. So what's the real advantage against unsigned char?